# Checking if the app is using the proper version of node.js

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a basic Express app with a package.json that looks like this

```
{
    "name": "blog",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "~3.0.0"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": "0.9"
    }
}
```

Obviously `node` itself doesn't care about contents of this file. Is there a way to start an app so that `npm` would read it and report an error?

Answer (score 3):

since the package.json is only a json file you can easily load and parse it, then compare the engines.node value with `process.version` and report an error.

no need to do something with npm here.

Comment: That's how it's done now, but I want to leverage `npm` ability to use  "~", ">=" etc in version strings.

Comment: You can use [the node-semver package](https://github.com/isaacs/node-semver) to parse and compare those kinds of version specifications (specifically looking at the `satisfies` function).